# How to retrieve statement metrics from postgres using metricbeat

Tags: postgresql, metricbeat, elk

I am seeing database,bgwriter,activity metrics in kibana, 
but not statement metrics, do we have to change the postgres.conf to retrieve 
statement metrics

```
metricbeat.yml - 
- module: postgresql
  enabled: true
  metricsets:
      - database
      - bgwriter
      - activity
      - statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the postgresql `pg_stat_statements` exentsion. See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgstatstatements.html

Add the following to your `postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

And execute the following as a privileged user:

```
create extension pg_stat_statements;
```